# Error: Class PbuploadMediaGridDataProvider does not exist

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, uicomponent

I am creating grid in Admin, while adding `ui_component` and related resource Model  to my module I am getting this error:

> Class PbuploadMediaGridDataProvider does not exist.

frontname = pbupload

Module= PinkBlue_CatalogUpload

Here is ui_component `pbupload_media_listing.xml`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Folder</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="pbupload_media_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">PbuploadMediaGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">media_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">media_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">media_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="pbupload/media/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Folders</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected Media Folders?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="edit">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                        <item name="callback" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_columns_editor</item>
                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">editSelected</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="mageplaza_betterslider_banner_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">banner_id</item>
                    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="pbupload/media/inlineEdit"/>
                        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">media_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="banner_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="url">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Url</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="type">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">PinkBlue\CatalogUpload\Model\Media\Source\Type</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Type</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="updated_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Modified</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="PinkBlue\CatalogUpload\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\MediaActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">media_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
    <container name="sticky">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/sticky/sticky</item>
                <item name="toolbarProvider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.listing_top</item>
                <item name="listingProvider" xsi:type="string">pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_listing.pbupload_media_columns</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </container>
</listing>
```

and here is Pinkblue\CatalogUpload\Model\ResourceModel\Media\Grid\Collection

```
<?php
namespace Pinkblue\CatalogUpload\Model\ResourceModel\Media\Grid;

class Collection extends \Pinkblue\CatalogUpload\Model\ResourceModel\Media\Collection implements \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface
{
    /**
     * Aggregations
     * 
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface
     */
    protected $aggregations;

    /**
     * constructor
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param $mainTable
     * @param $eventPrefix
     * @param $eventObject
     * @param $resourceModel
     * @param $model
     * @param $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }


    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface
     */
    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface $aggregations
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }


    /**
     * Retrieve all ids for collection
     * Backward compatibility with EAV collection
     *
     * @param int $limit
     * @param int $offset
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
    }

    /**
     * Get search criteria.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface|null
     */
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Set search criteria.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total count.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    /**
     * Set total count.
     *
     * @param int $totalCount
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set items list.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface[] $items
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dataProvider` class must be an existing class.

In your case you used `PbuploadMediaGridDataProvider`. I assumed that you based on development on what Magento does out of the box.

However, most of the time M2 uses a virtual type for the data provider classes.

I also assume that you want to use your `Pinkblue\CatalogUpload\Model\ResourceModel\Media\Grid\Collection` as the data provider.

To implement that you can add the following to your `di.xml` or create it :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="PbuploadMediaGridCollectionFactoryForReporting" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="pbupload_media_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Pinkblue\CatalogUpload\Model\ResourceModel\Media\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="PbuploadMediaGridReporting" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Reporting">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collectionFactory" xsi:type="object">PbuploadMediaGridCollectionFactoryForReporting</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="PbuploadMediaGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="reporting" xsi:type="object">PbuploadMediaGridReporting</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Comment: i have not created di.xml yet

Comment: @supriyamishra I've edited my answer you can create it with the content I gave in my answer

Comment: I have read somewhere <datasource> class name should be matched with aurgument in  di.xml  but here is some difference is it correct ?

Comment: @supriyamishra with the code I provide `dataProvider` class name will match a virtual type class from the `di.xml` ;)

Comment: Not registered handle pbupload_media_listing_data_source error is coming ?

Comment: @supriyamishra I made a typo, see my edited answer ;)

Comment: Missing required argument $mainTable of Pinkblue\CatalogUpload\Model\ResourceModel\Media\Grid\Collection.  what should I try nw?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47751/discussion-between-supriya-mishra-and-raphael-at-digital-pianism).